# How to summarize number of diseases present for different age groups?

Tags: sas

I have dataset of people with multimorbidity. The diseases are developing at different time points.

```
ID  time_ enrolled   Baseline_age dis1 dis1_time dis2 dis2_time dis_3 dis3_time
1     2005.5           35         1     2010.7    1     2012.1   0     2015.3
2     2004.3           49         0     2011.3    1     2013.8   0     2017.9
...
```

I have summarized the proportion of people at each baseline age group 30-39, 40-49, etc, for having one, two or three diseases. Now I would like to count the number of people who e.g. at the age of 40-49 years had one, two or three diseases. And the proportion would be the proportion they represent of all individuals while at that age.
First I thought to calculate the maximum age when they have developed their last disease, but then the categories of the younger age groups will be empty, also the older age groups will be empty, e.g. if the person has developed all the diseases before the age of 70. Does anyone have any thoughts how could I approach this problem? I am using SAS for programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of considerations:

- processing is easier when data is transposed into a tall & thin structure

  - one row per id/disease flag
- in some cases the person may have a 'gap' in age range

  - example: disease at 20-29 and next at 40-49
    this to me is implicit zero count of diseases at age range 30-39.  This implicit would be important (and should be considered) in computing 30-39 disease proportion over all ids.
  - filling in 'gaps' is easily accomplished when a standardized value for age is used for an age in a range.  The 'standard' value can be computed using a custom format and a custom informat.
  - adding dummy records for gaps should only occur for ages between enroll date and last disease date

Approach

- transpose age and flag for each id and enroll age
- use `MEANS` to sum flags for each id age(standardized) to get count of concurrent diseases in an age range
- left join a cross join ids and ages with sums for gap fill in
- use `MEANS` again to count age and age*flag_count
- use `DATA` step to compute proportion of counts [age*flag_count]/[age]

Sample code

```
* custom format and informat for standardizing age;

proc format;
  value agegrp
    20-29 = '20-29'
    30-39 = '30-39'
    40-49 = '40-49'
    50-59 = '50-59'
    60-69 = '60-69'
    70-79 = '70-79'
    80-89 = '80-89'
    90-high = '90 + '
  ;
  invalue agegrp
    '20-29' = 20
    '30-39' = 30
    '40-49' = 40
    '50-59' = 50
    '60-69' = 60
    '70-79' = 70
    '80-89' = 80
    '90 + ' = 90
  ;
run;

* generate some sample data;

data have;
  call streaminit(123);
 
  do id = 1 to 10000;
    enrolled = '01jan2000'd + rand('integer', 1, 3650);
    age = 20 + rand('integer', 59);

    flag1 = rand('uniform') < 0.25;
    date1 = enrolled + rand('integer',2500);

    flag2 = rand('uniform') < 0.25;
    date2 = date1 + rand('integer',2500);

    flag3 = rand('uniform') < 0.25;
    date3 = date2 + rand('integer',2500);

    output;
  end;
  format enrolled date: yymmdd10. flag: 1.;
run;

* compute age at each disease flag time point;

data stage1;
  set have;
  
  age1 = age + intck('year', enrolled, date1);
  age2 = age + intck('year', enrolled, date2);
  age3 = age + intck('year', enrolled, date3);
run;

* parallel array based transposition of ages and flags;

data stage2;
  set stage1;

  * map age in range to first value in range;
  * need for later when creating zero counts for intermediate age ranges not in data;
  * counts of zero counts needed to compute proportion;

  enroll_age = input(put(age,agegrp.),agegrp.);

  age = input(put(age1,agegrp.),agegrp.); flag = flag1; output;
  age = input(put(age2,agegrp.),agegrp.); flag = flag2; output;
  age = input(put(age3,agegrp.),agegrp.); flag = flag3; output;

  keep id enroll_age age flag;
  format enroll_age age 4. flag 1.;
run;

ods listing;

* compute number of simultaneous diseases in age range;

proc means noprint nway data=stage2;
  class id enroll_age age;
  format enroll_age age agegrp.;
  var flag;
  output out=stage3(drop= _type_ _freq_) sum=flag_count;
run;

* data for cross join;

data all_ages;
  do age = 20 to 90 by 10;
    output;
  end;
  format age agegrp.;
run;

* combine all_ages with each id so as to get a zero count
* for a range not present between enroll_date and max date;

proc sql;
  create table stage4 as
  select ids.id, ages.age, coalesce(stage3.flag_count,0) as flag_count
  from
    ( select distinct id from stage3 ) as ids
  cross join 
    all_ages as ages
  left join 
    stage3
    on ids.id = stage3.id and ages.age = stage3.age
  group by
    ids.id
  having
    ages.age between min(stage3.enroll_age) and max(stage3.age)
  order by
    ids.id, age
  ;
quit;

* compute counts;

proc means noprint data=stage4;
  class age flag_count;
  output out=stage5 N(id)=;
  types age age*flag_count;
run;

* compute proportions;

data want;
  merge
    stage5 (where=(_type_=2) rename=_freq_=age_freq)
    stage5 (where=(_type_=3) rename=_freq_=flag_count_freq)
  ;
  by age;

  age_flag_count_proportion = flag_count_freq / age_freq;

  format age_flag_count_proportion percent5.;

  keep age flag_count age_freq flag_count_freq age_flag_count_proportion;
  format flag_count 1.;
run;
```

Example output data

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Richard, I wonder if it is possible to adjust these ratios also for sex and region?

Comment: Very likely, depends on what you mean by *adjust* and how you plan to partition your population given the two additional categorical variables **sex** and **region**.  You might need to create additional formats and informats for sex and region.

Comment: Thanks, Richard for this explanation. Another question is, how could we summarize if we want to find the proportion of people with different combinations of the diseases at each age group? Again, I have summarized it for the baseline age, but now I would like to count the number of people who e.g. at the age of 40-49 years had disease1+disease2, etc. And the proportion would be the proportion they represent of all individuals while at that age. Do you have any thoughts how could we do it? I think it should work similar to your idea for the number of diseases.

Comment: Another question in StackOverflow should be posted as another question.  Be sure to include examples of the desired output.  Extended discussion is better on a site such as communities.sas.com

Comment: I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64341318/how-to-summarize-different-combinations-of-diseases-for-different-age-groups, please feel free to have a look