# How to summarize different combinations of diseases for different age groups?

Tags: sas

We have a study of people who have been enrolled to a study at different time points and from different age groups. They have been followed up for two decades and during this time they have developed 1-5 diseases. The diseases are developing at different time points.
Here is the code for an example data in SAS:

```
proc format;
  value agegrp
    30-39 = '30-39'
    40-49 = '40-49'
    50-59 = '50-59'
    60-69 = '60-69'
    70-79 = '70-79'
  ;
  invalue agegrp
    '30-39' = 30
    '40-49' = 40
    '50-59' = 50
    '60-69' = 60
    '70-79' = 70
  ;
run;

* generate some sample data;
%macro RandBetween(min, max);
   (&min + floor((1+&max-&min)*rand("uniform")))
%mend;


data have;
  call streaminit(123);
 
  do id = 1 to 10000;
    enrolled = '01jan2000'd + (1 + floor((1+3650-1)*rand("uniform")));
    age = 30 + %RandBetween(0, 49);

    flag1 = rand('uniform') < 0.25;
    date1 = enrolled + %RandBetween(0, 2500);

    flag2 = rand('uniform') < 0.25;
    date2 = date1 + %RandBetween(0,2500);

    flag3 = rand('uniform') < 0.25;
    date3 = date2 + %RandBetween(0,2500);

    flag4 = rand('uniform') < 0.25;
    date4 = date3 + %RandBetween(0,2500);

    flag5 = rand('uniform') < 0.25;
    date5 = date4 + %RandBetween(0,2500);
    output;
  end;
 format enrolled date: yymmdd10. flag: 1.;
run;
```

I have summarized the proportion of people with different combinations of disease for their age at the baseline. But now I want to find the number of people having different combinations of diseases at each age group. e.g.to count the number of people who at the age of 40-49 years had disease1+disease2, etc. And the proportion would be the proportion they represent of all individuals while at that age.

The output should look as follows:

```
Disease combination           30-39  40-49  50-59  60-69  70-79
------------------------------------------------------------------
Combinations of length 2       xx%    yy%  ...
flag1+flag2
flag2+flag3
...


length 3

length 4

length 5
```

Do you have any thoughts how could one do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is somewhat unusual from a diagnoses standpoint, however, if the flags are for diagnosis of a disease or disease family that follows some temporal progression model the data might make sense.

Considerations

- The age at disease flag date needs to be separately computed for each flag.
- Double pivoting creates wide structure with flags segregated by at_age grouping
- `TABULATE` has built-in percentage calculations.
- The mapping of a *'disease flag asserts condition is present'* state to it's corresponding disease name is effectuated using a custom format

Example:

Consider the flagging of 5 diagnoses related to the dreaded Werewolf progression.

```
proc format;
  value agegrp
    30-39 = '30-39'
    40-49 = '40-49'
    50-59 = '50-59'
    60-69 = '60-69'
    70-79 = '70-79'
    80-high = '80 +'
  ;
  invalue agegrp
    '30-39' = 30
    '40-49' = 40
    '50-59' = 50
    '60-69' = 60
    '70-79' = 70
  ;

  * flag1 to flag5 are progression of Werewolf!;
  value $flag_state_to_disease
    flag1_1='Animal Bite'      
    flag2_1='Hallucination'    
    flag3_1='Onychogryphosis'  
    flag4_1='Hypertrichosis'   
    flag5_1='Hyperdontia'
    other=' '
  ;
run;

* generate some sample data;
%macro RandBetween(min, max);
   (&min + floor((1+&max-&min)*rand("uniform")))
%mend;


data have;
  call streaminit(123);
 
  do id = 1 to 10000;
    enrolled = '01jan2000'd + (1 + floor((1+3650-1)*rand("uniform")));
    age_at_enroll = 30 + %RandBetween(0, 49);

    flag1 = rand('uniform') < 0.25;              
    date1 = enrolled + %RandBetween(0, 2500);

    flag2 = rand('uniform') < 0.25;
    date2 = date1 + %RandBetween(0,2500);

    flag3 = rand('uniform') < 0.25;                
    date3 = date2 + %RandBetween(0,2500);

    flag4 = rand('uniform') < 0.25;
    date4 = date3 + %RandBetween(0,2500);

    flag5 = rand('uniform') < 0.25;
    date5 = date4 + %RandBetween(0,2500);
    output;
  end;

  * force a 5 disease situation for each age group;
  enrolled = '01jan2000'd;
  do age_at_enroll = 30 to 70 by 10;
    flag1=1; flag2=1; flag3=1; flag4=1; flag5=1; 
    date1=enrolled+10; date2=date1+10; date3=date2+10; date4=date3+10; date5=date4+10;
    output;
    id + 1;
  end;

  format enrolled date: yymmdd10. flag: 1.;
run;

* pivot to tall structure;
data tall(keep=id at_age disease);
  set have;
  array dates date1-date5;
  array flags flag1-flag5;

  * row wise transposition of flags as disease names and computed at_age;
  do _n_ = 1 to dim(dates);
    at_age = age_at_enroll + intck('year', enrolled, dates(_n_));
    flag_state = catx('_', vname(flags(_n_)), flags(_n_));
    disease = put(flag_state, flag_state_to_disease.);
    output;
  end;
run;

* pivot back to wide structure, segregating within id the at_age groups;
proc transpose data=tall out=wide1 (label='diseases per id agegroup') prefix=disease;
  by id at_age;
  var disease;
  format at_age agegrp. ;
run;

* computed values for tabulation;
data wide2(keep=at_age disease_count disease_list);
  set wide1;
  disease_count = 5 - cmiss(of disease1-disease5);
  length disease_list $100;
  disease_list = coalescec (catx(', ', of disease1-disease5), '* NONE *');
run;

ods html file='tabulation.html' style=plateau;
title;

proc tabulate data=wide2;
  class disease_count disease_list at_age;
  table 
    disease_count*disease_list
    ,
    at_age * (n*f=comma9. colpctn)
    /
    nocellmerge
  ;
run;
ods html close;
```

HTML output image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating indicator columns by concatenating all flags together where `0_0_0_0_0` indicates no diseases and `1_1_1_1_1` indicates all five diseases and in between include all possible combinations. Then join different aggregation levels for numerator and denominator of percentages, all while creating conditional columns.

**`data`**

Add indicator columns

```
data have;
    set have;
    select;
        when (age >= 30 & age <= 39) age_group='30-39';
        when (age >= 40 & age <= 49) age_group='40-49';
        when (age >= 50 & age <= 59) age_group='50-59';
        when (age >= 60 & age <= 69) age_group='60-69';
        when (age >= 70 & age <= 79) age_group='70-79';
        otherwise age_group='';
    end;

    length = catx('_', flag1, flag2, flag3, flag4, flag5);
    format length $char10.;
run;
```

**`proc sql`**

Run different level aggregation with conditional columns

```sql
proc sql;
    create table final_table as 
    select len.length format=$char10.
           , SUM(case when len.age_group = '30-39' then len.length_count / age.age_count else . end) as Pct_30_39 format=percent10.2
           , SUM(case when len.age_group = '40-49' then len.length_count / age.age_count else . end) as Pct_40_49 format=percent10.2
           , SUM(case when len.age_group = '50-59' then len.length_count / age.age_count else . end) as Pct_50_59 format=percent10.2
           , SUM(case when len.age_group = '60-69' then len.length_count / age.age_count else . end) as Pct_60_69 format=percent10.2
           , SUM(case when len.age_group = '70-79' then len.length_count / age.age_count else . end) as Pct_70_79 format=percent10.2

    from 
       (select h.age_group
               , h.length
               , COUNT(*) as length_count
        from have h
        group by h.age_group
                 , h.length) as len
    inner join
       (select h.age_group
               , COUNT(*) as age_count
        from have h
        group by h.age_group) as age
      on len.age_group = age.age_group

     group by len.length;
quit;
```

**Output**

Total rows is 32 as confirmed by sum of combinations:

<sub>5</sub>5<sub>0</sub> + <sub>5</sub>5<sub>1</sub> + <sub>5</sub>5<sub>2</sub> + <sub>5</sub>5<sub>3</sub> + <sub>5</sub>5<sub>4</sub> + <sub>5</sub>5<sub>5</sub>  = 1 + 5 + 10 + 10 + 5 + 1 = 32

[image: Table Output]

To check, all columns equal 1

```
proc means data = final_table sum; run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think this is summarizing the disease combinations for the age at baseline, but I want to summarize for the age at which they have developed the disease. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64288326/how-to-summarize-number-of-diseases-present-for-different-age-groups/64290539?noredirect=1#comment113774038_64290539